# C++ Knapsack Algorithm Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, priority-queue, knapsack-problem

My algorithm for the best-first, branch and bound knapsack problem is giving me a max profit of 80 when it should be 90. I'm wondering where I went wrong... my thinking is the priority queue is a bit off.

Given input:

```
4,16 // 4 items to follow , 16 capacity knapsack
2,40 // item1.. weighs 2, costs 40
5,30 // item2.. weighs 5, costs 30
10,50 // item3.. weighs 10, costs 50
5,10 // item4.. weighs 5, costs 10
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>

typedef struct node{
    int level;
    int profit;
    int weight;
    int bound;
} node;

struct node_cmp{
    bool operator()(const node& a, const node& b) const{
        return a.bound < b.bound;
    }
};

int KWF2(int i, int weight, int profit, int *w, int *p, int C, int n){
    int weight1 = weight;
    int bound = profit;
    int j;
    float x[n+1];
    for(j = i; j <= n; j++){
        x[j] = 0;
    }

    while(weight1 < C && (i <= n)){

        if(weight1 + w[i] <= C){
            x[i] = 1;
            weight1 += w[i];
            bound += p[i];
        }
        else{
            x[i] = ((float)C-(float)weight1)/(float)w[i];
            weight1 = C;
            bound = bound + p[i] * x[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return bound;
}

void knapsack(int *w, int *p, int C, int maxprofit, int n){
    int maxp = maxprofit;
    std::priority_queue<node,std::vector<node>,node_cmp> PQ;
    node u,v;

    v.level = 0;
    v.profit = 0;
    v.weight = 0;
    v.bound = KWF2(v.level+1,v.weight,v.profit,w,p,C,n);
    PQ.push(v);

    while(!PQ.empty()){
        v = PQ.top();
        PQ.pop();
        if(v.bound > maxp){
            u.level = v.level + 1;
            //yes child
            u.weight = v.weight + w[u.level];
            u.profit = v.profit + p[u.level];

            if((u.weight <= C) && (u.profit > maxp)){
                maxp = u.profit;
            }

            if(KWF2(u.level+1,u.weight,u.profit,w,p,C,n) > maxp){
                PQ.push(u);
            }

            //no child
            u.weight = v.weight;
            u.profit = v.profit;
            u.bound = KWF2(u.level+1,u.weight,u.profit,w,p,C,n);
            if(u.bound > maxp){
                PQ.push(u);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",maxp);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int n,C;
    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    fscanf(in,"%d,%d",&n,&C);

    int w[n+1];
    int p[n+1];
    float ratio[n+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fscanf(in,"%d,%d",&w[i+1],&p[i+1]);
        ratio[i+1] = (float)p[i+1]/(float)w[i+1];
    }

    int temp_w,temp_p;
    float temp_r;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++){
            if(ratio[i] < ratio[j]){
                temp_w = w[i];
                temp_p = p[i];
                temp_r = ratio[i];

                w[i] = w[j];
                p[i] = p[j];
                ratio[i] = ratio[j];

                w[j] = temp_w;
                p[j] = temp_p;
                ratio[j] = ratio[i];
            }
        }
    }

    int maxprofit = 0;
    knapsack(w,p,C,maxprofit,n);

    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are solving knapsack problem with greedy algorithm (that maximizes current profit) - it may miss the best solution.

Comment: Trying to understand what all of those lines of code are doing would take forever, and I'm just a volunteer here, like everyone else. If you are able to add (possibly extensive) commenting to your code to clarify what you think you are doing at each step, I would be much more happy to help. As it is, this looks like gibberish to me. :-/